# splitting string in dictionary

Tags: c#

How do I split the following string

```
string s = "username=bill&password=mypassword";

Dictionary<string,string> stringd = SplitTheString(s);
```

such that I could capture it as follows:

```
string username = stringd.First().Key;
string password = stringd.First().Values;
```

Please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can populate the dictionary list like so:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
string s = "username=bill&password=mypassword";

foreach (string x in s.Split('&'))
{
    string[] values = x.Split('=');
    dictionary.Add(values[0], values[1]);
}
```

this would allow you to access them like so:

```
string username = dictionary["username"];
string password = dictionary["password"];
```

NOTE: keep in mind there is no validation in this function, it assumes your input string is correctly formatted

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to parse a query string - this is already built in, you can use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) for this:

```
string input = "username=bill&password=mypassword";
var col = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(input);
string username = col["username"];
string password = col["password"];
```

Comment: a nice solution, but not quite a dictionary as asked for ;-)

Comment: @musefan - And yet, probably the best way to get to a dictionary. Strongly typed parsing and a result set that can be trivially converted to one.

Answer (score 2):

I think something similar to this should work

```
public Dictionary<string, string> SplitTheStrings(s) {
    var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();  
    var a = s.Split('&');
    foreach(string x in a) {
        var b = x.Split('=');
        d.Add(b[0], b[1]);
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        var splitString = "username=bill&password=pass";
        var splits = new char[2];
        splits[0] = '=';
        splits[1] = '&';
        var items = splitString.Split(splits);
        var list = new Dictionary<string, string> {{items[1], items[3]}};

        var username = list.First().Key;
        var password = list.First().Value;
```

this my also work

Answer (score 1):

If Keys will not repeat

```
var dict = s.Split('&').Select( i=>
{
    var t = i.Split('=');
    return  new {Key=t[0], Value=t[1]};}
).ToDictionary(i=>i.Key, i=>i.Value);
```

If Keys can repeat

```
    string s = "username=bill&password=mypassword";
    var dict = s.Split('&').Select( i=>
    {
        var t = i.Split('=');
        return  new {Key=t[0], Value=t[1]};}
    ).ToLookup(i=>i.Key, i=>i.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are better, easier to read, simpler, less prone to bugs, etc, but an alternate solution is to use a regular expression like this to extract all the keys and values:

```
MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches("username=bill&password=mypassword&","(.*?)=(.*?)&");
```

Each match in the match collection will have two groups, a group for the key text and a group for the value text.

I am not too good at regular expressions so I don't know how to get it to match without adding the trailing '&' to the input string...